# Generate a Brainf_ck program that outputs a string of given length

Tags: kolmogorov-complexity, restricted-source, brainfuck, metagolf, code-generation

Your friend is trying to break into a vault that has a peculiar locking system: it requires a certain number of gentle knocks in a particular spot. Your friend discovered the number (which is in the range 1...99999) and possesses a gadget that produces the required knocks. However, the gadget is a Brainfuck interpreter! So your friend needs to feed it a Brainfuck program, which, obviously, should be as short as possible (the gadget's I/O is slow).

Your task is to help him! Write a program or a subroutine, in any language, that accepts as input a number `N`, and outputs a Brainfuck program, which takes no input and outputs a string of printable ASCII characters (excluding the space character - codes in the range 33...126) of length `N`.

Example: for input `10`, the output might be

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++..........
```

(but I am sure it can be shortened!)

Your score will be the sum of lengths of your outputs for the following values of `N` (they are random numbers):

```
55
68
15
28
841
838
522
846
4898
9004
9363
3810
13230
67175
37231
44701
```

Oh, and you will be transmitting your code (the generator program) to your friend by Twitter. So make sure it's [140 characters](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/counting-characters) or less!

---

P.S. The Brainfuck language has many variants. Let's assume the tape is infinite in both directions (or "circular and large enough"), and the cells have 32-bit int capacity (finite and able to hold numbers up to 99999). Also, no wrapping: when a cell overflows, the machine self-destructs!

Comment: "following values of N (they are random numbers)"
reminded me of http://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: Just for reference, the space character (character code 32) is usually included in the printable ASCII range. It doesn't really make a difference for the challenge since you've defined the range explicitly though.

Comment: Can we assume cells in brainfuck to be arbitrary width integers? If not, how and when do they wrap?

Comment: It would be nice to assume at least being able to contain 67175 + a few.

Comment: @anatolyg I realized that later. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Python 2, score: 1021

I've just realized that this contest is pretty old but still, since I came up with a better solution than those posted, I posted it as well.

Here's a 102 byte python script that does the job:

```
n=input()
s='>'
while n:
    s+='>'+'+'*(n%5+1);n/=5
print s+'[->[-<+++++>]<<]<+++++++[>+++++<-]>>[-<.>]'
```

The idea is to use base 5 encoding for N (best base at least for the current inputs, which do not seem very "random" by the way, looks like they were arbitrarily chosen by OP), and to write a generic Brainfuck algorithm to decode a number of arbitrary length (the number is encoded with each digit increased by one in order to detect the end of conversion). I chose to print character 35 `#`, character 36 `$` is equivalent.

You may run the following bash script to get the score:

```
i=0
while read p; do
  i=$((i+`echo $p | python convert.py | wc -m`))
done
echo $i
```

With a more advanced program that replaces encoding with multiplication for small numbers and chooses the best base for encoding each number, I can reach 958 Brainfuck characters, but Python is far too verbose (and I'm a pretty bad/lazy golfer) in order to get the converter into 144 bytes!

Comment: This is a great idea! Maybe I'll use it once to improve this answer (wrote a script in Python to get score less than 950, but I don't know any golfing language to make it short enough).

Answer (score 8):

### BrainF***, score: 193,313

It's not under 140 characters (it's 147, so close!!), so this can't win, but I thought it was cool.

Prints 43 plus signs, then `N` periods. Not very optimal.

```
>++++++[>+++++++<-]>+[->+>+<<]>[->.<]<<+[[-]>[-],[+[-----------[>[-]++++++[<------>-]<--<<[->>++++++++++<<]>>[-<<+>>]<+>]]]<]>>>+++<<<<[>>>>.<<<<-]
```

If anyone can help shorten this I would love it.

Comment: I guess with Brainfuck it would be enough to make a "subroutine" that receives its input on the tape - no need to read from "standard input device".

Comment: @anatolyg That makes it much easier - probably about 80 or 90 characters. Should I change it?

Answer (score 5):

## J, Total score = 1481

*(For my previous entry and explanation check revision history.)*

```
f10=.('>++++++++++<';'')rplc~;@([:(<@('+++++[>+++++++<-]>>+',;@((<'[>++++++++++')#~#)),[<@(']',~'<-','<.>'#~],[,])"0 #-i.@# )10#.inv])
```

This function generates nested BF loops based on the base10 digits of the input number. Checking all reasonable bases and choosing the smallest BF code would improve the score with a small amount.

BF programs for the test set:

```
   f10 every 55 68 15 28 841 838 522 846 4898 9004 9363 3810 13230 67175 37231 44701
+++++[>+++++++<-]>>+[>++++++++++[-<<.....>>]<-<.....>]                                                                                     
+++++[>+++++++<-]>>+[>++++++++++[-<<......>>]<-<........>]                                                                                 
+++++[>+++++++<-]>>+[>++++++++++[-<<.>>]<-<.....>]                                                                                         
+++++[>+++++++<-]>>+[>++++++++++[-<<..>>]<-<........>]                                                                                     
+++++[>+++++++<-]>>+[>++++++++++[>++++++++++[-<<<........>>>]<-<<....>>]<-<.>]                                                             
+++++[>+++++++<-]>>+[>++++++++++[>++++++++++[-<<<........>>>]<-<<...>>]<-<........>]                                                       
+++++[>+++++++<-]>>+[>++++++++++[>++++++++++[-<<<.....>>>]<-<<..>>]<-<..>]                                                                 
+++++[>+++++++<-]>>+[>++++++++++[>++++++++++[-<<<........>>>]<-<<....>>]<-<......>]                                                        
+++++[>+++++++<-]>>+[>++++++++++[>++++++++++[>++++++++++[-<<<<....>>>>]<-<<<........>>>]<-<<.........>>]<-<........>]                      
+++++[>+++++++<-]>>+[>++++++++++[>++++++++++[>++++++++++[-<<<<.........>>>>]<-<<<>>>]<-<<>>]<-<....>]                                      
+++++[>+++++++<-]>>+[>++++++++++[>++++++++++[>++++++++++[-<<<<.........>>>>]<-<<<...>>>]<-<<......>>]<-<...>]                              
+++++[>+++++++<-]>>+[>++++++++++[>++++++++++[>++++++++++[-<<<<...>>>>]<-<<<........>>>]<-<<.>>]<-<>]                                       
+++++[>+++++++<-]>>+[>++++++++++[>++++++++++[>++++++++++[>++++++++++[-<<<<<.>>>>>]<-<<<<...>>>>]<-<<<..>>>]<-<<...>>]<-<>]                 
+++++[>+++++++<-]>>+[>++++++++++[>++++++++++[>++++++++++[>++++++++++[-<<<<<......>>>>>]<-<<<<.......>>>>]<-<<<.>>>]<-<<.......>>]<-<.....>]
+++++[>+++++++<-]>>+[>++++++++++[>++++++++++[>++++++++++[>++++++++++[-<<<<<...>>>>>]<-<<<<.......>>>>]<-<<<..>>>]<-<<...>>]<-<.>]          
+++++[>+++++++<-]>>+[>++++++++++[>++++++++++[>++++++++++[>++++++++++[-<<<<<....>>>>>]<-<<<<....>>>>]<-<<<.......>>>]<-<<>>]<-<.>]
```

Computing score on the test set:

```
   +/#@> f10 each 55 68 15 28 841 838 522 846 4898 9004 9363 3810 13230 67175 37231 44701
1481
```

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 1702

Reconstruct numbers using factors of N + x.

```
+holN+]++">>"*"+"Q"<<"mjk(">>"j">"m*"+"kP+Qd"<[[->[->+>+<<]>>[-<<+>>]<<<]>[-]>[-<<+>>]<<<]>"*"-"d"<<")50"++++++[>++++++<-]>>[<.>-]"
```

Comment: For `2` this outputs `++`. now which doesn't print anything in BF.

Comment: @randomra Good catch, this happened while updating, I'll fix it, give me a few.

Comment: @randomra Should be fixed, made the score slightly higher (of course).

Answer (score 3):

## CJam, <strike>52</strike> <strike>74</strike> 108 bytes, total = <strike>1304</strike> <strike>1244</strike> 1210

```
ri5b_,1>{(_3<{\(@5*+}*\+}*W%)\{T+_2>:T5*-_0>"-+"=\z*}%\T+'+*a+W%{"[->+++++<]>"\}*">x[>x<-]<[->>.<<]"'x/'+6**
```

A test script (slow in the online interpreter):

```
q~]
{
_[0:T;
5b_,1>{(_3<{\(@5*+}*\+}*W%)\{T+_2>:T5*-_0>"-+"=\z*}%\T+'+*a+W%{"[->+++++<]>"\}*">x[>x<-]<[->>.<<]"'x/'+6**
]s
_[L:RL@0\
"-+><.]"['('){+\_{)}0?@\}{@\+\_{)}0?}{R1$c+:R;}]:`"]a"{{_aa+1$4G#%{:~~1}{;0}?}g}`+a+er:~:~
];R,@=!"Error."N+*o
}%s,
```

Comment: I didn't see the part about self-destruction. But it will never overflow anyway.

Comment: How does it work?

Comment: @anatolyg The first version simply generate the number in base 5. Later versions added a special case for the first two digits and also used decrement.

Comment: @user23013 Oh, sorry, haven't seen the spec changes. (Updated my answer accordingly.)

Answer (score 2):

## Befunge-98, N + 41, total = 193281

```
&>'+\:v
v^-1,\_
' >1-:v
>v^,+'_
,'    :
>ff3++^
>2f*+v
^>/9+:,
>'>,61v
, v*6+<
^/2,:<@
v >+2+,
>'<,']^
```

I know it's bad, but I felt like writing some Befunge today. The best part of Befunge is that the programs are even less understandible than the actual golf languages, especially when they reuse code :D

Uses a similar algorithm to Martin Büttner's [CJam answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/47904/30164):

```
(N +'s)>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<[->.<]
```

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, 40 + N, Total: 193265

```
'+33*'>'+l~*"[<.>-]"
```

Just to get this started, here is the baseline solution. It generates the following code:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>_[<.>-]
```

where `_` is `N` copies of `+`.

[Run the generator here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code='%2B33*'%3E'%2Bl~*%22%5B%3C.%3E-%5D%22&input=55)

Answer (score 1):

### Befunge-93 - 24 + N, total = 193009

```
&>">>]-<]-<++++>[++++>[+++"v
v  ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, <
>:v
,v_@
"1
.-
"
^<
```

This uses a prefix of `+++[>++++[>++++<-]<-]>>` to set the first tape index to '0' with 24 characters.
The Befunge program is very basic and outputs that along with N '.' characters.

Comment: Now that I see this I don't know why I was thinking my loop would be any better...