# Encoding an URL in brainfuck

Tags: kolmogorov-complexity, restricted-source, brainfuck, metagolf, code-generation

[Inspired by this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47895/generate-a-brainf-ck-program-that-outputs-a-string-of-given-length), your goal today is to encode an URL in brainfuck.

My browser has been hacked! The location bar has been turned into a brainfuck interpreter. I need a program that turns an URL into a brainfuck program. My computer is also very slow, so if the brainfuck program is small it's better.

Oh and I only have one working tab left open, my twitter. So you can only send me the program in a tweet.

---

1. Write a program that fits in a tweet (140 characters) in any language that takes a string as input and outputs a brainfuck program.
2. This brainfuck program will be run without input and will generate an output.
3. This output will be inserted into the location bar of Google Chrome, and executed.
4. If the behaviour of Google Chrome is identical to the behaviour you would get by entering the input string from #1, then the solution is valid. *Redirection by URL shorteners is considered different behaviour - stay at least on the same domain.*

You may assume the brainfuck interpreter has infinite precision signed integers in each cell and an unlimited amount of cells.

Your score is determined by the sum of the lengths of the brainfuck programs generated to encode the following set of URLs:

```
https://www.google.com/
https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47895/
http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/examples.html
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding
ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/
https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth/blob/master/doc.txt#L92
http://ftp.gnu.org/non-gnu/nethack/nethack-3.4.0.tar.gz.back-RSN.README
```

Smallest score wins.

Comment: May we assume that the input would be formatted like this: `http://www.google.com/` or will it ever simply be `google.com`? (Both are valid as far as Google Chrome is concerned, but your list only contains the full forms) P.S. I *almost* have a desire to write an extension for chrome that does this...

Comment: @BrainSteel The input for your encoder will be exactly as stated as in the question (each line is one input). The output of the brainfuck may be any format accepted by Google Chrome, as long as it has the same behaviour as the original input string. So if your program takes input `http://www.google.com/` the brainfuck program it produces may output `google.com`, `www.google.com`, etc, because they all result in the same page. But for example `ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/` is not the same as `ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/`.

Comment: Ah, thank you for clarifying! Sorry, I'm a bit slow this morning.

Comment: I would like to clarify that I failed, and that `ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/` is indeed the same as `ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/` in Google Chrome. This makes the challenge a bit easier than I intended, but such is life. I won't change the requirements, so it's safe to just strip off anything before `://`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Pyth - 118 bytes, score: 154 + 567 + 597 + 620 + 530 + 875 + 1092 = <strike>6630</strike> <strike>6623</strike> <strike>4653</strike> 4435

Now using the factor multiplication algo!

This is a pretty simple algorithm, although slightly better than the above ones. <strike>I was planning to use Pyth, but with the current algorithm Python fits<140 bytes</strike>.

```
=zecz"//"=z?>z4}"www."zz=z?Pzqez\/zFNzKCNJ/^K.5 1=d\+pk+holN[?*-KZd>KZ*-ZK\-+\>*dK+++++\>*Jd"[>"*Jd"<-]>"*-K*JJd)\.=ZK
```

It first strips out the `http://` by using `split("//")` and the `www.` and `/` at the end. Then it uses the min function to check which is the best of the the three options that is considered:

1. Use `+` or `-` to update current cell value to desired cell value
2. Go to new cell and just fill with `+`'s
3. Go to new cell and use multiplication to update by doing sqrt(n)*sqrt(n)+remainder since square has minimum perimeter of constant area. http://cydathria.com/bf/bf_ex3.html

I then always put a `.` to output each char.

A detailed explanation of the new code is coming soon. I kind of half-assed the golfing, especially the stripping of `www.` and the `/` at the end but I can't be bothered since I'm 20 bytes under the limit.

This surprisingly works on the `ftp://` urls since this is chrome and chrome automatically makes `ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/` into `ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/`

I plan to next use a dictionary to store the cell values and see if the character was already made in a cell.

---

### Brainfuck Omnibox Extension

That's right! After I saw @BrainSteel's comment, I knew I had to make it. This doesn't take over the entire omnibox, only when you do <kbd>bf</kbd>,<kbd>tab</kbd>. Also since the omnibox api is weird, it doesn't let me forward the code to the omnibox, I have to handle it myself. So I do my own `http://` checking and then set the tab's url.

Since I didn't feel like paying the $5 necessary to put your extension on the webstore, you guys will have to install it manually. Just download the zip from here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0qkKIzGc0QiNzBzVUJjZkRIZ0k/view?usp=sharing, unzip, go into the extensions page in chrome, click dev mode option box on top-right, and load the unpacked extension.

Hope you guys enjoy! :)

Comment: This won't work on the `ftp://` URL.

Comment: @Pietu1998 that's what I thought at first but Chrome surprised me. Try putting in ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/ in your address bar and Chrome will make it ftp:// ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/

Comment: @Maltysen Oops. I had intentionally included that URL to prevent this optimization, but it looks like I failed. [This URL](http://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/) is indeed different, but it seems Chrome is indeed smart enough to recognize and add `ftp://`. Oh well.

Answer (score 4):

## C, <s>140</s> <s>134</s> <s>132</s> <s>138</s> <s>128</s> 139 Bytes

## 263 + 816 + 911 + 955 + 827 + 1355 + 1779 = <s>7269</s> 6906 bytes

Update: 6 bytes less, thanks to nutki!

Update again, 128 bytes. Code is significantly less readable. It now attempts to strip the URL of `ftp://`, too.

Update the third, at 139 bytes. Code is a bit more readable, and got rid of some nasty undefined behavior. Now, if the site name is preceded by `www.`, it is stripped. I got under 7k, but I think I must concede to Maltysen with Pyth. Well done.

```
#define p putchar
a;main(int c,char**V){while(*V[1]++-47);*++V+=1;for(*V+=**V-'w'?0:4;c=**V;*V+=1,p(46))for(;c-a;a+=c>a?1:-1)p(c>a?43:45);}
```

Unraveled a bit:

```
#define p putchar
a;
main(int c,char**V){
    while(*V[1]++-47);
    *++V+=1;
    for(*V+=**V-'w'?0:4;c=**V;*V+=1,p(46))
        for(;c-a;a+=c>a?1:-1)
            p(c>a?43:45);
}
```

This code takes a URL at the command line, and converts it into BF using only `.`,`-`, and `+`. The code makes an attempt to strip the string of `ftp://`,`http://`,`https://`, and `www.` before converting to BF. Here is a list of outputs of the outputs:

```
google.com/
codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47895/
golfscript.com/golfscript/examples.html
en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding
ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/
github.com/isaacg1/pyth/blob/master/doc.txt#L92
ftp.gnu.org/non-gnu/nethack/nethack-3.4.0.tar.gz.back-RSN.README
```

Comment: How about using one inner loop: `for(;c-a;a+=c>a,a-=c<a)p(c>a?43:45)` should work.

Comment: @nutki Impressive! Thank you!

Comment: _"Note that if we may assume no URL begins with anything other than http://, https://, or ftp://, we can drop 10 bytes from this solution."_ Your solution only has to work for the dataset above, so you may assume whatever you want, as long as the dataset will still be handled correctly/

Comment: @orlp Hooray! That sounds like 12 bytes to play with! Thank you for this challenge, it's been great fun!

Answer (score 4):

## Brainfuck, 77 bytes, Score = 31647

Score is the sum of `codepoint+4` for every character.

```
+++++[>+++++++++<-]>+[>++>+>++>+>+<<<<<-]>+>->->>--->,[[<.>-]<<.<.<.<.>>>>>,]
```

(Uses BF implementation with EOF = 0.)

Example:

```
input:
!bar

output:
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.[-]++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.[-]+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.[-]++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.[-]
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6) - 137 bytes, score - 7413

This uses only <kbd>.</kbd>, <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd>. You can test it in Firefox console.

```
B=s=>[...s.replace(/^h.+\/\//,'')].map((c,i,a)=>(v=i?c[C]()-a[i-1][C]():c[C='charCodeAt']())?'-+'[v>0|0].repeat(v>0?v:-v):'').join('.')+'.'
```

This is my score counter:

```
[
    'https://www.google.com/',
    'http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47895/',
    'http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/examples.html',
    'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding',
    'ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/',
    'https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth/blob/master/doc.txt#L92',
    'http://ftp.gnu.org/non-gnu/nethack/nethack-3.4.0.tar.gz.back-RSN.README'
].map(B).join('').length
```